# How do loops and char arrays work in C ?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have a program that runs exactly how I want it to be:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 15

void passwordCheck (int digit)
{
static char buf[BUF_SIZE] ;
  static int  i = 0;
  char pw[]="1234" ;
  int pw_size = sizeof(pw)-1 ;
  int ret ;

  if (digit == 13)
  {
    for(i=0;i<BUF_SIZE;i++){                     //why do I need this? 
    }
    ret = memcmp(buf, pw, 4) ;                      //compares the array with the pw
      if (ret == 0 && buf[pw_size] == 0) 
      {
      printf("Access granted\n") ;
      }
      else
      {
      printf("Access denied\n") ;
      }
  }

  else {
     if (i > ((int)sizeof(buf) - 2))          //sets all values to 0 ?  
     {
        i = 0;
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf)) ;
     }
     buf[i] = digit ;                  //stores a value
     buf[i++] = digit ;                //stores a values at the next stage   
  }
}
```

It checks if the user puts in the right password, if so Access is granted if not access is denied. Here's a [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7339db07dc98c426)

But I am having problems with understanding.

So `static int i` is used so that i doesn't become `0` everytime when `passwordCheck` is called?

So if the user doesn't press `13`, `passwordCheck` stores all values in an array via these two lines

```
buf[i] = digit ; 
buf[i++] = digit ;
```

if the function is called the first time, this if statement sets all values in the array to 0:

```
 if (i > ((int)sizeof(buf) - 2))
     {
        i = 0;
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf)) ;
     }
```

Then, when the user presses `13` the content of the array will be check and via
`memcmp` and if it matches Access is granted, if not Access is denied.

But here, in particular, I am wondering why do I need this for loop:

```
 for(i=0;i<BUF_SIZE;i++){
        }
```

If I comment it out the programm only gives me access one time and then never again. So I am assuming what it does is it resets all values in the area to `NULL`, so the same thing as `memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf)) ;` ? If that is the case, why, isn't it just a loop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a word parser digesting one character at a time. It resets after a full word is parsed. The full word ends with a carriage return `\r` ascii(13).

The function itself is meaningless without the main code showing how the function is being called.

Let's digest each block in the code.

`if (digit == 13)`

This checks if it is the end of the password `\r`. In this block, it resets `i` to greater than the size of `buf - 2`. This was done using a `for` loop but it can simply set `i = 15`. This is necessary so the next re-try the code knows it's a fresh new password. You will notice that in this code it compares the first 4 bytes of `buf` with the first 4 bytes of `pw` and it ensures that `buf` is terminated with `\0`. If it didn't check the termination, then `12345` will pass.

The else condition handles the initialization of `buf` and the storage of the characters passed to it.

In this block you will notice that it checks if `i` is greater than `sizeof (buf) -2`. This is the condition they used to signify that `buf` needs to be reset to `0`s. Hence the `for` loop in the previous block which could have been simplified by setting the value of `i` with an assignment expression `i = 15`.

The 2nd line that stores digit into `buf` does the same thing as the previous line does, and in addition it increments i. The previous line becomes unnecessary.

The use of static storage makes the value of `i` persist across each function call. Finally, this is not thread safe.

Comment: There is a link in the question, having the main code and program output.

Comment: Yes I read the code, that's why I was able to come up with this answer. Future readers of this question will get lost when your demo code is removed. I also wrote a shortened version of your code here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cd1052290aefd24

Comment: I realized you aren't the OP. I kept referring to the question and code as yours.

Comment: No. Not at all. Thread safe re-entrant codes don't use static variables. To make it thread safe re-entrant, you can modify the function to receive additional parameters which will replace the role of `buf` and `i`.

Answer (score 2):

As your `for` loop is empty, it's only side-action is (you can replace it with):

```
i = BUF_SIZE;
```

As a side note, it is highly possible that the compiler / optimizer is already producing that code in the output, and there will be no overhead from having the (unneeded) `for`.

This is only called when you send the password terminator `13`. After that, at the next call (for another password), the function will take again the main `else` branch, and because `i` was previously set to `BUF_SIZE`, will execute this, resetting your counter:

```
    i = 0;
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf)) ;
```

Your main `if` could be simplified, and will work the same:

```
  if (digit == 13)
  {
    ret = memcmp(buf, pw, pw_size) ;   //compares the array with the pw
      if (ret == 0 && i == pw_size) 
      {
      printf("Access granted\n") ;
      }
      else
      {
      printf("Access denied\n") ;
      }
    i = 0; // Reset for next password input
  }

  else {
     buf[i++] = digit ; //store the value on current position and after increment the pos
  }
```

Comment: ok, and then what happens? if I give i a value that means it starts from the beginning of the array again?

Comment: I added some details in the answer.

Comment: +1 @nnn - your answer is almost perfect. Please add `memset(buf, 0 sizeof(buf));` either before or after `i=0;`. Without it, the password will fail if the previous password is longer than 4 characters.

Comment: Please disregard my previous message. I just realized you are checking the value of `i`.

Comment: It shouldn't fail. I'm also checking the `i` value (actual buf size). The OP is checking a char from buf and is needed is his case. Edit: Ok, I saw late your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Without this for loop you can not check the `else` statement until your `buf` full or size is 15. Because when the `digit` is 13 then you reset the buffer by checking the value of `i` in `else` statement which is `15` by using the `for` loop. It just wastes time . so you can write `i=15//max size of buffer`